# Magento2 How to add custom attribute to billing information of order rest api response

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api, custom-attributes

I want to add a custom attribute to the billing information section of order rest API response instead of showing in extension attribute section. please anyone can help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write more with example.